# How to check if write to Dynamodb is successful for PutItemAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having some confusion on how to check if Dynamo Client was successful for a putItemAsync. I am using the .NET library.

```
var res = _dynamoClient.PutItemAsync(request).Result;
if(res.HttpStatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Error {res.HttpStatusCode} with putting to DynamoDB for {request.Item} to {request.TableName}");
            }
```

Is there a correct way to check if the Dyanmo write was successful? Or do I just check the status code? The problem arose because of write throttling and I would like to log an error when ever a PutItemAsync fails. Do I have to catch any exceptions maybe? Or is the way I am doing it valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AmazonDynamoDBClient.PutItemAsync()` will throw an exception if the write wasn't successful.

Possible exceptions are:

- `ConditionalCheckFailedException` - A condition specified in the operation could not be evaluated.
- `InternalServerErrorException` - An error occurred on the server side.
- `ItemCollectionSizeLimitExceededException` - An item collection is too large.
- `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` - Your request rate is too high. The AWS SDKs for DynamoDB automatically retry requests that receive this exception. Your request is eventually successful, unless your retry queue is too large to finish.
- `RequestLimitExceededException` - Throughput exceeds the current throughput quota for your account.
- `ResourceNotFoundException` - The operation tried to access a nonexistent table or index.
- `TransactionConflictException` - Operation was rejected because there is an ongoing transaction for the item.

If the method call returns without an exception, you can safely assume that the item has been written.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer, is that the case for all other methods as well. For example DeleteItemAsync?

Comment: Yes, you can generally rely on the AWS SDK throwing an exception whenever the API Call fails, either because of insufficient permissions, an actual error, or specific logic, like conditions not being met.